Cosine similarity usefulness for continuous variables
I have been asked to identify a 'cohort' of products similar to productA, and someone suggested I identify a set of relevant features and compute the cosine similarity between each possible similar product and productA. The features I'll be using are mostly numeric, although I will include some discrete variables as well.
This led to a general question I have about when cosine similarity is useful. For example, if I have two vectors:
p1 = [10, 20, 40]

p2 = [1000, 2000, 4000]

In this case, cosine_sim(p1, p2) = 1.
But what if, while the vectors are proportional to each other, the difference in magnitude of each vector value is meaningful. As an example, if one of the features I'm considering is the avg acceleration of product growth for productA and productB, a 10% vs 1000% acceleration is meaningfully different. For discrete values, I understand more why this measure makes sense but am strugglingly to understand it's usefulness for continuous variables.
Is there a different similarity measure I should be using? Am I thinking about this correctly?

It sounds like your current feature vector, $p_i = [p_{~i,1}, p_{~i,2}, p_{~i,3}]$, does not encapsulate all features you consider important.  You might consider adding features to an augmented $p_i^\prime  =  [ p_{~i,1}, p_{~i,2}, p_{~i,3}, \textrm{scale}_i, \ldots  ]$.

One possible use for cosine similarity is for compositional data, which (after square root transformation) can be viewed as vectors on a hypersphere. See, e.g., this thread. In general, cosine similarity is natural similarity/distance measure for data that can be viewed as directional vectors.

Wikipedia puts it this way:

The most noteworthy property of cosine similarity is that it reflects a relative, rather than absolute, comparison of the individual vector dimensions. For any positive constant $a$ and vector $V$, the vectors $V$ and $a V$ are maximally similar. The measure is thus most appropriate for data where frequency is more important than absolute values; notably, term frequency in documents.

Your sense is thus correct: if you care about the magnitudes of vector elements, then cosine similarity is not a good choice.
There's another problem with cosine similarity: it includes the origin (all vector elements of 0) regardless of whether there are any such values in the data set. Accordingly, simple shifts in values can greatly change the cosine similarity. See this page, for example. If you center all the vectors before you do the cosine similarity, then you just end up with the Pearson correlation coefficient. If there isn't some critical reason to include the origin in your similarity measure, the Pearson correlation is a safer choice (although it also is a measure of relative rather than absolute similarity).
As is often the case, the best answer is: the usefulness of cosine similarity depends on whether it's appropriate for your type of data, based on your understanding of the subject matter. It can be useful for frequencies or related types of data, like the compositional data noted in another answer. Otherwise, be cautious.
